# How to integrate CMU sphinx with Unity 3D engine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cmusphinx

I am working on a Vuforia Speech recognition project to control 3D objects through voice. After googling i found out that CMU SPHINX, a open source software is great for speech recognition. I have tried integrating it with unity, but didn't suceed. Have anyone tried integrating CMU sphinx with unity? Or else, is there any tutorial for this?

Comment: There are many implementations which you can find in Google in 5 seconds https://github.com/cmuartfab/unitysphinx

Comment: I need to support android @Nikolay Shmyrev. cmuartfab currently only supports for windows! I have also tried  https://github.com/ispikit/ispikit-unity which is for android but it throwing a error on initial import to Unity assest folder.

Comment: You can ask here a proper question about specific issue you see providing all the details instead of this one then.

Comment: I am also working on a similar project ! Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet! @KarthikKPN